# Progressive IDs - clone and insert div onclick with jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, clone

In a webform I am currently cloning and inserting a div onclick using jQuery, this is now working OK. However I am having issues trying to assign progressive ID's to all cloned elements within the DIV.

How do I assign new or progressive IDs to each cloned element within "#issueDiv1"?

Also how can I get the removeButton to remove the previous cloned DIV?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addButton').click(function(){
         $('#issueDiv1').clone().insertAfter('#issueDiv1');
    });
});
```

DIV

```
<div id="issueDiv">
   <div id="issueDiv1">
      <fieldset id="yourIssue">
         <legend>Request Details</legend>
         <p>Please choose what your issue(s) is below. (Please note if you have multiple balances out you will need to submit each one separately)</p>
         <p>
            <label>Your Request:</label>
            <select type="text" class="required" name="request_details[]" id="requestdetails1" onchange="setspecificDetails(this);">
               <option value="">Select...</option>
               <option value="Trust Balance out">Trust Balance out</option>
               <option value="Bank Balance out">Bank Balance out</option>
               <option value="Tixc out">Tixc out</option>
               <option value="Ins out">Ins out</option>
               <option value="3rd Party out">3rd Party out</option>
               <option value="Comm out">Comm out</option>
               <option value="Tax out">Tax out</option>
               <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
         </p>
      </fieldset>
      <div id="trustBalance" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput" id="datetrustbalanceout1" name="date_trust_balance_out"/> *</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did an amount search bring back any further details that reate to the issue?</label></p>
         <textarea id="trustamountsearch1" name="trust_amount_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did the closed ledgers with non-zero balances search in Sherlock bring back any further information,</label></p>
         <p><label> if so please provide details below or attach screenhot:</label></p>
         <textarea id="trustclosedledgerssearch1" name="trust_closedledgers_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Please prodive any further details that might be relevant to the issue:</label></p>
         <textarea id="trustfurtherdetails1" name="trust_further_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
      <div id="bankBalance" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput" id="datebankbalanceout1" name="date_bank_balance_out"/> *</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did an amount search bring back any further details that reate to the issue?</label></p>
         <textarea id="bankamountsearch1" name="bank_amount_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did the compare bank rec history against statement search in Sherlock bring back any infomation?</label></p>
         <p><label>Please provide details below or attach screenshot.</label></p>
         <textarea id="comparebanksearch1" name="compare_bank_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Please prodive any further details that might be relevant to the issue:</label></p>
         <textarea id="bankfurtherdetails1" name="bank_further_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
      <div id="tixcOut" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>(Please make sure you have carried out an amount search to provide further details on the issue)</label></p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput" id="datetixcout1" name="date_tixc_out"/> *</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did the statements and payments search in Sherlock bring back any further details that relate to the issue?</label></p>
         <p><label> Please provide details below or attach screenshot:</label>
         <p>
            <textarea id="tixcsearch1" name="tixc_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required">
            </textArea> *
            <br />
            <br />
         <p><label>Please prodive any further details that might be relevant to the issue:</label></p>
         <textarea id="tixcfurtherdetails1" name="tixc_further_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
      <div id="insOut" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>(Please make sure you have carried out an amount search to provide further details on the issue)</label></p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput" id="dateinsout1" name="date_ins_out"/> *</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did the statements and payments search in Sherlock bring back any further details that relate to the issue?</label></p>
         <p><label> Please provide details below or attach screenshot:</label>
         <p>
            <textarea id="insOutsearch1" name="insOut_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required">
            </textArea> *
            <br />
            <br />
         <p><label>Please prodive any further details that might be relevant to the issue:</label></p>
         <textarea id="insOutfurtherdetails1" name="insOut_further_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
      <div id="3rdParty" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>(Please make sure you have carried out an amount search to provide further details on the issue)</label></p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput" id="date3rdpartyout1" name="date_3rdparty_out"/> *</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did the fin unbalances 3P types search in Sherlock bring back any further details that relate to the issue?</label></p>
         <p><label> Please provide details below or attach screenshot:</label>
         <p>
            <textarea id="3rdpartysearch1" name="3rdparty_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required">
            </textArea> *
            <br />
            <br />
         <p><label>Please prodive any further details that might be relevant to the issue:</label></p>
         <textarea id="3rdpartyfurtherdetails1" name="3rdparty_further_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
      <div id="commOut" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>(Please make sure you have carried out an amount search to provide further details on the issue)</label></p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput" id="datecommout1" name="date_comm_out"/> *</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did the statements and payments search in Sherlock bring back any further details that relate to the issue?</label></p>
         <p><label> Please provide details below or attach screenshot:</label>
         <p>
            <textarea id="commOutsearch1" name="commOut_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required">
            </textArea> *
            <br />
            <br />
         <p><label>Please prodive any further details that might be relevant to the issue:</label></p>
         <textarea id="commOutfurtherdetails1" name="commOut_further_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
      <div id="taxOut" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>(Please make sure you have carried out an amount search to provide further details on the issue)</label></p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Date this balance went out according to the NBS auto-validation history search in Sherlock?</label><input type="text" class="required date-picker tinyInput" id="datetaxout1" name="date_tax_out"/> *</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <p><label>Did the statements and payments search in Sherlock bring back any further details that relate to the issue?</label></p>
         <p><label> Please provide details below or attach screenshot:</label>
         <p>
            <textarea id="taxOutsearch1" name="taxOut_search" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required">
            </textArea> *
            <br />
            <br />
         <p><label>Please prodive any further details that might be relevant to the issue:</label></p>
         <textarea id="taxOutfurtherdetails1" name="taxOut_further_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="1" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
      <div id="otherDiv" class="greyBox">
         <p><label>Please state the problem below and provide as much detail as possible (along with relevant screenshots):</label></p>
         <textarea id="otherdetails1" name="other_details" class="required" cols="90" rows="5" class="required"></textArea>
         *
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

BUTTON

```
<p><input type='button' value='Add another issue' id='addButton' class='clone' style='width: 200px; height: 40px' /></p>
    <p><input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton' class='remove' style='width: 200px; height: 40px' /></p>
```

Comment: instead of **id="issueDiv1"** try it using class **class="issueDiv1"**

Answer (score 0):

ok, lets clear something up real quick, try to avoid using ids if you can. Maintaining these id's will be a nightmare. You have to keep track of what is removed, what is added, what is modified and it gets very messy.

Instead, use a class, and make use of jQuery's `.find`, `.parent`, `.children`, and `this` functions so you can find html elements relative to each other.

for your example it looks like you want unique ids so you don't have duplicates. I suggest doing the following so you don't worry about duplicate ids:

put your issueDivs inside a wrapper div and give your div's a class

```
<div id='issues'>
 <div class='issueDiv'></div>
 <div class='issueDiv'></div>
</div>
```

then do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addButton').click(function(){
         $('#issues').append($('.issueDiv').first().clone());
         //this gets the first div with class 'issueDiv'
         //there's also a .last() function, 
         //which will get the last one in the list
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried first and last clone and the addButton seems unresponsive. I am using jQuery version 1.7.2 - are the first and last versions compatible with that version?

Answer (score 0):

> For maintaining the progressive id for the issue div you can store id value to global var in jquery.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var issueid =2; 
   $(document).on('click','#addButton',function(){
    var node =$('<div id="issueDiv' + issueid + '">'+$('issueDiv1').html()+'</div>');
    node.insertAfter('#issueDiv'+(issueid -1));
       issueid = issueid + 1;
    })
$(document).on('click','#removeButton',function(){
    var node=$('#issueDiv'+issueid);
     node.remove();
     issueid = issueid - 1;
});
});});
```